Is there a language that loudness alone is phonemic?
The prominence of a stressed syllable can be measured by: Loudness VS Duration VS Pitch
Amplitude usually comes together with duration (and/or) pitch. Usually pitch and duration are more important than loudness in a stress system.
There are tonal languages with stress and languages with vowel length contrasts having stress (Estonian, English).
Loudness is seldom singled out as the sole factor to distinguish a stressed syllable. Is there a language that a stressed syllable is louder but there is no change in pitch and duration? Is there a language that has minimal pairs contrasting loudness alone?
